# Trying to redirect if condition isn't met

Tags: python, flask

I'm new to flask. I need help trying to redirect the user to the guest page if they don't enter 'admin' as their name in the url. I'm getting an Internal Server Error for some reason. In my terminal:

File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Flask_Blog\app.py", line 23, in hello_user
    return redirect(url_for('hello_guest', guest=name))
NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Nov/2018 13:24:34] "GET /user/john HTTP/1.1" 500 -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def home():
    greeting = 'Alexander Salako'
    return render_template('home.html', my_variable=greeting)

@app.route('/admin')
def hello_admin():
    return 'Hello admin'

@app.route('/guest/<guest>')
def hello_guest(guest):
    return 'Hello guest %s'. % guest

@app.route('/user/<name>')
def hello_user(name):
    if name == 'admin':
        return redirect(url_for('hello_admin'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('hello_guest', guest=name))

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: What's wrong with this code? It seems like you have done what you wanted.

Comment: sorry. I'm getting an Internal server Error. In my terminal i'm getting this message:

 File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Flask_Blog\app.py", line 23, in hello_user
    return redirect(url_for('hello_guest', guest=name))
NameError: name 'redirect' is not defined

Comment: below line can be responsible for that "from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for"

The error is saying that dependencies are not properly imported I guess

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're importing redirect?

Comment: It's next to the render_template import.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any file named **flask.py** in your project? If yes then rename it. This error is occurring because redirect function is not found in your flask library

Comment: No I don't have a flask.py in my project, I have an app.py file.